# JSON query with JsonPath by sibling node condition

Tags: json, jsonpath

This is a problem I am having for JSON parsing with JsonPath. I do come up with a solution but not sure if it is the best/only.

Suppose I have a simple JSON like this,

```
{
   "name": "Bill",
   "age" : 33
}
```

I need to select the "name" node if the value of "age" node is less than 40. If it is not, just return an empty array.

Could anyone share your solution? I have mine as one answer below.

Answer (score 2):

First I have to use `$.` to turn the JSON into an array of JSON, ie,

```
        {
          "name": "Bill",
          "age" : 33
        }
```

to

```
        [
            {
              "name": "Bill",
              "age" : 33
            }
        ]
```

Then I can apply `$[?(@.age < 40)].name`